# Yii2 uploaded image doesn't show up

Tags: php, image, file-upload, yii2

I use [this yii2 module](https://github.com/CostaRico/yii2-images) for an image uploading purposes.

My upload folder is:

```
C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\MYAPPNAME\WEB\UPLOAD
├───cache
├───global
└───store
    └───Products
        └───Product15
```

Where store is the folder for original pictures and the cache is for the resized ones. yii2-images is configured like this:

```
'yii2images' => [
            'class' => 'rico\yii2images\Module',
            //be sure, that permissions ok
            //if you cant avoid permission errors you have to create "images" folder in web root manually and set 777 permissions
            'imagesStorePath' => 'upload/store', //path to origin images
            'imagesCachePath' => 'upload/cache', //path to resized copies
            'graphicsLibrary' => 'GD', //but really its better to use 'Imagick'
            'placeHolderPath' => '@webroot/upload/store/no-image.png', // if you want to get placeholder when image not exists, string will be processed by Yii::getAlias
],
```

and my Product model upload method is:

```
public function upload()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            $path = 'upload/store/' . $this->image->baseName . '.' . $this->image->extension;
            $this->image->saveAs($path);
            $this->attachImage($path);
            @unlink($path);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Uploading images work. I mean, they fisically appear where they should. I load image

```
<?php $img = $model->getImage(); ?>
```

and in my DetailView widget instead of 'img':

```
[
                'attribute' => 'image',
                'value' => "<img src='{$img->getUrl()}'>",
                'format' => 'html',
            ],
```

And what I get instead of a rendered image is:

```
image-by-item-and-alias?item=Product15&dirtyAlias=71273544a6-1.jpg
```

I have no idea where this "image-by-item-and-aliasitem=Product15&dirtyAlias?" part even comes from when it actually must be something like:

```
Products\Product15\71273544a6-1.jpg
```

and given format html parameter it must therefore render an image.

Can you please pinpoint me to the source of this error?

Comment: You say _"And what I get is:"_ etc but... What **exactly** does your expected result look like if you don't want the current result of `image-by....etc` text? Does it work if you try: `"<img src='{$img}'>"`?

Comment: It should render an image located upload folder. Yes, it works if i hard code it. I'll update my question to indicate a problem in a more clear way.

Comment: Can you share `getUrl()` implementation?

Comment: @rob006
https://github.com/CostaRico/yii2-images/blob/master/models/Image.php
Starting line 52.

Comment: Obviously this method is the source of such URL and in seems to be intentional - there is such action which serves images (in extremely inefficient way...): https://github.com/CostaRico/yii2-images/blob/master/controllers/ImagesController.php#L38 . I'm not sure why it is working in this way. If you want to change URL you may do this by overriding this method or playing with URL manager config.

Comment: @rob006
I'm pretty sure this package has been changed at some point in time and the manual I was following was simply outdated. I think there's no point in making it work, I'd be better of using just the built-in image serve module.